# Even and odd elements from list and count elements up to specific index in list, but shows error

Tags: list, prolog

I am making a prolog program to count even and odd elements from list and count elements up to a specific index(user given) in the list. But it shows Errors. I am new in prolog. Here is my code:

```
is_even(N) :- Y is N mod 2, Y=0.

split(Index,List,Left,Right) :-
   length(Left,Index),       % Actually CREATES a list of fresh variables if "Left" is unbound
   append(Left,Right,List).  % Demand that Left + Right = List.

create(L1):-read(Elem),create(Elem,L1).

create(-1,[]):-!. create(Elem,[Elem|T]):-read(Nextel),create(Nextel,T).

setval(Y8,0).
setval(Y9,0).

incr():-
 Y8 is Y8 + 1.

incb():-
 Y9 is Y9 + 1.
 
count(R):-
 ( is_even(R) -> incr();incb()).
 
dosomething([]).
 dosomething([R|T]) :- count(R), dosomething(T).
 
go:- write('Creating a list'),nl, write('Enter -1 to stop'),nl, create(L), nl, write('Enter index'),read(ID), split(ID,L,X1,X2), dosomething(X1), write(Y8), write(Y9).
```

It gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [14] _19326 is _19332+1
ERROR:   [11] dosomething([1,2]) at c:/users/v/documents/prolog/bw.pl:24
ERROR:   [10] go at c:/users/v/documents/prolog/bw.pl:26
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user:go) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1117
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code, maybe you should rethink it a simpler way.

First, a SW engineering principle valid in any programming language, states that you should avoid global variables, as far as possible. So, instead of `incr():- Y8 is Y8 + 1.`, you should use - for example - `Yn is Y + 1`.

Note also that since in Prolog variables are assign once, `Y8 is Y8 + 1` will **never** be true, and then the *predicate* incr/0 will always fail.

Another - minor - problem: `incr():-...` is a SWI-Prolog syntactic extension, introduced to support a restricted form of OOP, you should use instead the plain Prolog syntax `incr :- ...`.

Anyway, try to solve your assignment with a single 'loop', that is, a recursive predicate, where you pass down the index of the element to check, and get back the counters accounting for the properties you're asked to check. If I understand the question correctly, you should also check that elements are actually integers, count them, and apply the odd/even check only on them. In the following snippet, I use the *conventional* arguments ordering, placing the input before the output. You should place a cut in the appropriate place in the first clause of count/6, and - of course - provide an appropriate predicate update_counters/7.

```
count([E|Es],N,I, Int,Odd,Even) :-
  I=<N, I1 is I+1,
  count(Es,N,I1, Int1,Odd1,Even1),
  update_counters(E, Int1,Int, Odd1,Odd, Even1,Even).
count(_,_,_,0,0,0).
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I am a newbie to prolog so I made these mistakes. I have tried your approach but still not solving my problem. `count(_,_,_,0,0,0).
count([E|Es],N,I, Int,Odd,Even) :-
  I=<N, I1 is I+1,
  count(Es,N,I1, Int1,Odd1,Even1),
  update_counters(E, Int1,Int, Odd1,Odd, Even1,Even).

 
go:- write('Creating a list'),nl, write('Enter -1 to stop'),nl, create(L), nl, write('Enter index'),read(ID), count(X1,ID,0,0,0,0), write(Odd).` It show `_531` in output.

Comment: @DevanshMistry: I thought it should be clear that you **must** implement update_counters/7